# In which memory segment a program global and local static variables are saved

Tags: c, unix, memory, memory-management

As far as I know global static variables are stored in .Data and .Bss segment.

```
(global) static int i; ---> .BSS
(global) static int i=10; ---> .Data
```

If this is the case how multiple files which have same global staic variables access the variables from a memory location which is common to whole program.

Ex.

```
test.c

static int i=10;

void fun(){
   printf("%d", i );
}

test1.c

static int i=20;

void fun1(){
   printf("%d", i);
}
```

How test.c and test1.c resolve i from .Data segment?

My second question is in which segment of the program memory local static variables defined inside a functions are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various "namespaces" involved, and you should imagine that every object file contains its own "namespace" for its *static* variables.

Remember that the names are not stored inside the `.bss` (or the `.data`) segments.

To grossly simplify the picture imagine that when compiling into `foo.o` the "assembler" name of the `static int i;` inside `foo.c` would be something like `$foo.o$i`

<sup>This is not exactly the case, but you get the idea... Actually, you could inderstand that for `static` variables names are *not* generated into the object file. That static variable is still (grossly speaking) in `.bss` or `.data`, but its name is not visible.</sup>

Use [GNU objdump](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) to explore object [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) relocatable files.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, it clarified my first doubt. What about the local static variables?

Comment: `static` variables declared inside some function are `static` data, just their name is not accessible outside the function (so grossly speaking their assembly name is as if it was randomly generated).

Comment: Thanks Basile Starynkevitch :)

Answer (score 0):

A simplified explanation for the 2nd part of the question:-

```
1.Auto variables are stored in stack segment.

2.Uninitialized global variables are stored in BSS segment.

3.Initialized global variables and global static variables are stored in data segment.

***4.Local static variables are stored in data segment of the memory.***
```

## Scope and lifetime of a Variable

### Auto Variable

```
Scope:-    Only the function in which it is declared
Lifetime:- From when control enters the function in which it is declared till when control exits the function
```

### Global Variable

```
Scope:- Global variables can be accessed from anywhere in the program
Lifetime:- Entire life of program execution
```

### Global Static

```
Scope:- Global static variables can be accessed from anywhere inside the file in which they are declared
Lifetime:- Entire life of program execution
```

### Local Static

```
Scope:- Local static variables can be accessed inside the function where it is declared
Lifetime:- Entire life of program execution
```